# Vector version of integral that uses Beta function

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, beta-function

I learned that a complex integral can be computed by using Beta function.
I can compute $\begin{align*}
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}(1+x^{2})^{-n}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}$ by using the following relation.
$$
\begin{align*}
    B\Big(\frac{1}{2}, n-\frac{1}{2}\Big)
    &= \int_{0}^{\infty}
    \frac{t^{-1/2}}{(1+t)^{n}}\mathrm{d}t \\
    & = \int_{0}^{\infty}
    \frac{1/x}{(1+x^{2})^{n}}2x\mathrm{d}x \quad (\because \text{put} \ t =x^{2}, dt = 2x\mathrm{d}x)\\
    & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}
    \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{n}}\mathrm{d}x\\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
    \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{n}}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
$$
In this example, $x$ is a scalar. I would like to extend this to $z \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$. Specifically, I would like to compute
$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}(1+z^{T}z)^{-n}\mathrm{d}z.$$ Can I compute this using the same procedure with $t=z^{T}z$ as follows?

$$
\begin{align*}
    B\Big(\frac{1}{2}, n-\frac{1}{2}\Big)
    &= \int_{0}^{\infty}
    \frac{t^{-1/2}}{(1+t)^{n}}\mathrm{d}t \\
    & = \int_{0}^{\infty}
    \frac{z^{-1}}{(1+z^{T}z)^{n}}2z\mathrm{d}z \quad (\because \text{put} \ t =z^{T}z, dt = 2z\mathrm{d}z)\\
    & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}
    \frac{1}{(1+z^{T}z)^{n}}\mathrm{d}z\\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
    \frac{1}{(1+z^{T}z)^{n}}\mathrm{d}z.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I'm assuming the last three integrals are respect to $z$ instead of $x$, but what would mean integrating respect a vector? And what's the purpose on this anyway? Also I would think to place $\bar{z}^T z = ||z||^2$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the typo. I studied this when I was studying univariate probability density function. I needed to evaluate the integrations to get some coefficients. I would like to extend it to deal with multivariate pdf. This is my motivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in computing
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^n}\,dx = \omega_{d-1} \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{d-1}}{(1+r^2)^n}\,dr = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{d-1} \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{d/2-1}}{(1+r)^n} \,dr=\frac{\omega_{d-1}}{2}B\left(d/2, n-d/2\right),$$
with $\omega_{d-1}$ the area of $S^{d-1}$. Notice that the integral is well-defined only if $n>d/2$.

EDIT: changed $dx$ to $dr$.

Comment: Would you explain the transformation performed in the first equality and what is $S^{d-1}$?

Comment: The first equality is simply spherical coordinates. $S^{d-1}$ is the unit sphere $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: \| x\| =1 \}$.

Comment: Thank you. I think that I need to study the basics more, because I cannot figure out why unit sphere is showing up here. Would you tell me the name of this field so that I can find some references?

Comment: Would you explain the relation of $r$ and $x$?

Comment: I made a mistake and accidentally wrote $dx$ instead of $dr$. In spherical coordinates, $r=|x|$. If you're trying to study multivariable calculus, you will no doubt need to understand the change of variables formula and a specific case of it known as spherical coordinates. First start in 2D.

Comment: Thank you. I think now I understand it. You first write a volume element in terms of surface area of unit sphere and $r$.